# Github deploy key to allow a Docker Hub image to pull private gem with

Tags: authentication, docker, github, gem

Given repo "A", a Ruby project with a dependency on a gem, contained within another private Github repo, "B", I need to give Docker Hub permission to clone repo "B" when it builds the image.

I'm unsure of what the ideal setup for this is - ie, does it require an additional Github user for just the deploy keys for repo "B" or should it all work with the primary GH account I have already linked to Docker Hub and is working fine for accessing repo "A"?

Answer (score 0):

Under project settings, you can find an option `Deploy keys`, which should do what you want without an additional Gitlab user.

Add a public SSH-key here to authenticate your build machine.